# Built difference between values in the same column

Tags: dataframe, datatable

Lets say I have got the following datatable which has one column which gives back the first of each month from 2000 until 2005 and the second column gives back some values which are positive or negative.

What I want to do is that I want to build the difference between two observations from the same month but from different years.
So for example:
I want to calculate the difference between 2001-01-01 and 2000-01-01 and write the value in a new column in the same row where my 2001-01-01 date stands.

I want to do this for all my observations and for the ones who do not have a value in the previous year to compare to, just give back NA.

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no gaps in your data, you could use the `lag` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(sapply(2000:2005, function(x) paste(x, 1:12, 1, sep = "-"))),
                 Value = runif(72,0,1))

df$Difference <- df$Value-lag(df$Value, 12)

> df[1:24,]
         Date      Value   Difference
1  2000-01-01 0.83038968           NA
2  2000-02-01 0.85557483           NA
3  2000-03-01 0.41463862           NA
4  2000-04-01 0.16500688           NA
5  2000-05-01 0.89260904           NA
6  2000-06-01 0.21735933           NA
7  2000-07-01 0.96691686           NA
8  2000-08-01 0.99877057           NA
9  2000-09-01 0.96518311           NA
10 2000-10-01 0.68122410           NA
11 2000-11-01 0.85688662           NA
12 2000-12-01 0.97282720           NA
13 2001-01-01 0.83614146  0.005751778
14 2001-02-01 0.07967273 -0.775902097
15 2001-03-01 0.44373647  0.029097852
16 2001-04-01 0.35088593  0.185879052
17 2001-05-01 0.46240321 -0.430205836
18 2001-06-01 0.73177425  0.514414912
19 2001-07-01 0.52017554 -0.446741315
20 2001-08-01 0.52986486 -0.468905713
21 2001-09-01 0.14921003 -0.815973080
22 2001-10-01 0.25427134 -0.426952761
23 2001-11-01 0.36032777 -0.496558857
24 2001-12-01 0.20862578 -0.764201423
```

Comment: Hm, that should not matter at all. You'd still want to compare yearly values, right? It would just mean that the first non `NA` difference would come up for 2001-06-01.

Comment: Ohhhh, you were talking about building the data example! Sorry, misunderstood that. I'll add code for data starting at 2000-06-01 and ending at 2005-12-01, is that what you need? You could just subset the dataframe generated above with `df <- df[6:72,]`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try the `lubridate` package, very usefull to work with dates.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html